# Why doesn't $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x$ imply $g(f(x))=g(x)$?

Tags: functions

My question is, why doesn't $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x$ imply $g(f(x))=g(x)$.

Suppose for example $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f(x)=2$. We would like to find the fixed points of $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))$ i.e $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x$ which is easy to see $\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}=x$.

On the other hand, starting from $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x \Rightarrow g(f(x))=g(x) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x=2$. which is obviously a different answear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

And why should $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x$ imply $g(f(x))=g(x)$? Yes, if it is true that$$(\forall x):g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x,$$then$$(\forall x):g(f(x))=g(x).$$But from the fact that you have $g(f(g^{-1}(x)))=x$ for a *specific* $x$, you can't deduce that $g(f(x))=g(x)$, unless it happens that $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question amounts to asking why, if $h(g^{-1}(x))=x$, it doesn't follow that $h(x)=g(x)$.

The answer has to do with quantifiers. If you require that $h(g^{-1}(x))=x$ must hold for *all* $x$, then $h$ is indeed the inverse of $g^{-1}$, namely $g$. But your example shows this conclusion doesn't follow if you merely want the equation to hold for *some* $x$.